# File upload to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-classic-sites

I would like to use Google Sites to create a web site, where users can upload files. These uploaded files are stored at Google Drive, and data about the file is stored in a Google spreadsheet.

Are there any open-source applications or tutorials or libraries which can help make this possible? If not, can anybody explain how to do this?

Comment: Try Google Apps Script for that. See also Chrome Web Store for GAS apps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe JotForm is a solution -> http://www.jotform.com/blog/62-Send-Your-Form-Uploads-to-Google-Drive

Comment: Hi, perhaps you can put a snippet of the answer here so that this answer can stay valid when the link becomes dead? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in a web app script. This code generate a Submit button and then ask for a file that the user can upload directly to a preconfigured folder of Google Drive.

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
function doGet() {

  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName("DSRfile"));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton("Start Upload"));
  var form = app.createFormPanel();
  form.add(formContent);
  app.add(form);

  return app;
}

function doPost(e){
  var DSRload = e.parameter.DSRfile;
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while(folders.hasNext()){
    var folder = folders.next();
    if(folder.getName() === 'Expedientes'){
      var Doc = DriveApp.createFile(DSRload).getId();
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(Doc);
      folder.addFile(file);
      break;
    }
  }

  // Display a confirmation Message
  var label = app.createLabel("File Upload Successful");
  var clickHandler = app.createServerHandler('close');
  app.add(label).add(app.createButton('close this window', clickHandler));
  Logger.log('Va a cerrar 1');
 // return app ?;OJO con esta linea activa, muestra error
}

function close(){
  //OJO No entra a esta función
  Logger.log('Va a cerrar 2');
  //return UiApp.getActiveApplication().close();
  return app.close();
}
```